# installing ldap extension Docker

Tags: php, docker

Hey all I am trying to instal ldap extension on a Docker php:5.6-fm images i need ldap for my project.

I have tired to install the extension through Dockerfile like so:

```
RUN apt-get install php5-ldap -y
```

get this error:

```
The LDAP PHP extension is not enabled.
```

I have also find some 'suggestion' online like so:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install ldap
```

get this error:

```
An exception occured in driver: could not find driver
```

am i doing something wrong...? how do i install ldap on a docker image so that i can use it in my project...?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

```
# LDAP requirements
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ldap-utils libldap2-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install ldap for php
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y php5-ldap
```

The base image was:

```
FROM simplyintricate/mediawiki:1.26
```

Which is ultimately based on `debian:jessie`.